# X86 opcodes to move xmm register to general registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What is a short x86 instruction sequence to move the xmm0 register to eax and edx?

Comment: don't move between different domains except when necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which parts of xmm0 do you want?

```
movd     eax, xmm0
pextrd   edx, xmm0, 1    ; SSE4.1
```

gets the low 64bits of xmm0 into `edx:eax`.  If you need all 4 parts, consider storing to memory and reloading: store-forwarding to loads has more latency but better throughput than shuffles (fewer total uops), especially if you can use them as memory source operands instead of just `mov`.

(But if you want a horizontal sum or something, normally [do that with SIMD shuffles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction/35270026#35270026) like `pshufd` / `paddd` twice to reduce 4 elements to 2 then to 1.  Although `movd eax, xmm0` / `movdqa [esp], xmm0` store, and 3 scalar `add eax, [esp + 4/8/12]` is actually not bad for total uops or latency in this case, unlike scalar FP where latency is higher and you want the result in an XMM reg anyway.)

---

In 64bit code, `movq rax, xmm0` / `shld rdx, rax, 32` might be better than `pextrd`, and doesn't require SSE4.1.

A more normal `mov rdx, rax` / `shr rdx, 32` might be more efficient than SHLD, even though it costs more uops on Intel CPUs.  `shld` is slow on AMD CPUs, 8 uops on Zen.  (https://uops.info/)

BMI2 `rorx rdx, rax, 32` a good way to copy-and-shift, and is efficient on all CPUs that support it.  It of course leaves the high half of RDX probably non-zero, but that's fine.

Another option would be to `movd`/`movq`, if you're not close to bottlenecked on throughput for the single port they compete for.  On most CPUs they can't actually run in parallel, so movd/movq competing for a port does still cost latency for the 2nd one.  On a modern CPU with mov-elimination (Zen or IvyBridge), `mov rdx, rax` with zero latency is better.  But this does get your values in EAX and EDX zero-extended into RAX and RDX.

```
    movq  rdx, xmm0
    movd  eax, xmm0       ; or schedule this first if you can use EAX right away
    shr   rdx, 32
```

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for instruction-set references and other stuff.

See [Agner Fog's excellent Optimizing Assembly guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) for tips on which instructions to use.

Comment: Looking to get the bits from 64-bit double in xmm0 on x86 (32bit).

Comment: @tgiphil: ok, the low 64 is what I was guessing.  Is there some reason you haven't accepted this answer?  Do you need a 32bit SSE2 version using a vector shift or shuffle to get the second word down to element 0 for another `movd`?

Comment: Any way to do this on x86 without SSE4.1?

Comment: @tgiphil: `pshufd` + `movd`, or any other convenient shuffle to bring the element you want to the low 64 or 32 bits.